# build an array of integers inside a for next loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i got this far ... my data string, "num_str" contains a set of ~10 numbers, each separated by a comma. the last part of the string is a blank entry, so i use '.Trim' to avoid an error

```
Dim i As Integer
        Dim m_data() As String
        m_data = num_str.Split(",")

        For i = 0 To UBound(m_data)
            If m_data(i).Trim.Length > 0 Then
                MsgBox(Convert.ToInt32(m_data(i).Trim))
            End If
        Next i
```

as you can see from the Msgbox, each of the numbers successfully pass through the loop.

where i am stuck is how to place all of the 'Convert.ToInt32(m_data(i).Trim)' numbers, which are now presumably integers, into an array.

how do i build an array of integers inside the For / Next loop so i can find MAX and MIN and LAST

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way is more concise using the Select LINQ Operator.

```
Dim arrayOfInts = num_str.
                Split({","c}, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                Select(Function(v) Int32.Parse(v.Trim()))

Dim minInt = arrayOfInts.Min()
Dim maxint = arrayOfInts.Max()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize the array with the zero-based indexer. You can deduce it's initial size from the size of the `string()`:

```
Dim m_data = num_str.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim intArray(m_data.Length) As Int32

For i = 0 To m_data.Length - 1
    intArray(i) = Int32.Parse(m_data(i).Trim())
Next i
```

Note that i've also used the overload of `String.Split` which removes empty strings.